# VBA Color row cells if they are unequal to blank

Tags: vba, loops, colors

I'm using the code shown below to essentially make the first row of the spreadsheet color grey based on if the cell is empty or not. For example Cell A1 is not blank so color it grey, cell B1 is not blank so color it Grey but cell C1 is blank so don't color it at all. So far my script colors the whole row grey based on A1. Is there an alternative for this?

```
Sub test()
Dim c As Integer
c = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("A1"))
If c > 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 48
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with Excel-VBA, it's enourmously helpful to grasp the idea of `Objects` and `Collections` and how to loop them.

The Watch-window is your best friend here, as is the `With` keyword when writing code.

In your case:
a `Cell` is an object inside the `Worksheet.Cells`-collection (in your case, also an object inside the `ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Cells`-collection.

This does what you want, based on the information you gave us (you didnt specify that you do NOT want to loop the whole row ;) )

```
Option Explicit

Sub ColorCells()
    Dim objCell As Object
    With ActiveSheet
        With .Rows(1)
            For Each objCell In .Cells
                With objCell
                    If .Value > 0 Then .Interior.ColorIndex = 48
                End With
            Next objCell
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

This should give you an idea how Excel-`Objects` work.

Obviously, we can write this shorter:

```
Sub ColorCells()
    Dim objCell As Object
    For Each objCell In ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Cells
        If objCell.Value > 0 Then objCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 48
    Next objCell
End Sub
```

**Note:**

- This code will loop all 16k `Cells` in your `Row`. Obviously, we could stop at your last used `Cell`. However, since this runs in under a second, i left that out on purpose to keep the code clean
- While you could do this with conditional formatting, i support the idea of doing this with code ONCE, with no traces (that is, your conditional formats), left.
- I understand what you tried to do with `.CountA` and `.EntireRow`, this doesnt work here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm only new to VBA and it's been doing my head in, this works great.

Comment: Glad I could help. Be sure to mark the question as answered. Also consider if `objCell.Value > 0` really does what you need, of if you need something like `IsEmpty`.